# Azure AD + B2C, public facing website with enterprise and public users

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I want to build a public facing SaaS website. My users will either be:

1. enterprise customers and I will want them to be able to login with their corporate credentials.
2. non-enterprise customers. I will want the ability for them to register and use local credentials.

What would the solution look like? I'm thinking:

1. Use Azure AD and federate with the identity providers of my enterprise customers.
2. Use Azure B2C for my website, and configure #1 as my identity provider with the ability to create local accounts.

Is this the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can use Azure AD B2C for both the enterprise and non-enterprise customers

> Enterprise customers and I will want them to be able to login with
> their corporate credentials

You can use **Azure AD B2C policy** for the enterprise customers to use their corporate credentials for sign-in and sing-up

This policy uses a **multi-tenant Azure AD application** and the **/common** Azure AD endpoint to federate Azure AD B2C with any Microsoft 365 customer in the world

> Non-enterprise customers. I will want the ability for them to register
> and use local credentials

The users can sign-in and sign-up with their local accounts in the Azure AD B2C

You can refer this use-case provided by Microsoft for more info:

[Azure Active Directory B2C | Overview with Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview#example-woodgrove-groceries)